# change merged cells height

Tags: c#, openxml

I create C# programmatically excel file with merged cell. User OpenXml library. I need AutoFit merge cells as single cell. But I can't change merged cells hight. Is it possible to programmatically change?

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the cell height as far as i know. 
 But, a nice workaround would be to change the row heigth instead of the cell heigth.
Remember that in vb you can do something like this: `Rows(3).RowHeight = 25;`.
For the C# way you should take a look at this: [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.rowheight.aspx).
 Hope it helps!